# IEnumShellItems vs IShell­Folder::Enum­Objects (missing HWND argument)

Tags: shell, winapi

The "new" way to enumerate items (files) in windows shell is IEnumShellItems. The old way is IShell­Folder::Enum­Objects. However the two methods are not 100% equivalent. There are [articles](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150202-00/?p=44773/) explaining how to emulate the SHCONTF argument for superhidden files, but Enum­Objects also has a [HWND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775066(v=vs.85).aspx) parameter that can be used to tell a shell extension to get interactive, e.g. asking passwords and such. I cannot find how to pass such "get interactive" information through IEnumShellItems.

This is no idle questioning, I'm trying to convince windows explorer to ask for passwords from my 7z [shell extension](http://zabkat.com/blog/compressed-folder-shell-extension.htm)

thanks

Comment: I would just stick with the old API, given how badly the new stuff is documented.

Comment: I stick with the old stuff but explorer itself doesn't, and that's the problem!

Comment: Why does it matter what Explorer does? What does the new API do for you that the old one doesn't?

Comment: this is not for xplorer2. The above 7z NSE sometimes needs to ask for a password and explorer doesn't pass a HWND with EnumObjects, which is indicative of using IEnumShellItems. There must be some bind context that passes the HWND but where is it?

Comment: Oh so you're using it from the other side (as an implementer)? I'd missed that. Yes I guess it must be something like that. Probably a super-secret undocumented interface that can't possibly be revealed to the world because... reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The `L"UI During Binding"` bind context string can be a site? interface, try calling [`IUnknown_GetWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773814%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on it. `IUnknown_EnableModless` is probably a good idea as well (but undocumented?).